# PHP Cómo puedo recibir gran cantidad de variables POST numerados, si la cantidad también se recibe por POST?

Tags: php, variables, post, input

necesito recibir por $_POST una gran cantidad de variables numeradas variable.

Envío desde un form:

```
input id="var_A_1"
input id="var_B_1"
input id="var_C_1"

input id="var_A_2"
input id="var_B_2"
input id="var_C_2"
```

(El tipo letra es fijo y llega hasta N y el numero es variable, aveces hasta 10, 20, o 30)

Y para recibirlos los tengo así pero se hacen demasiadas lineas de código:

```
$var_A_1=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_A_1']));
$var_B_1=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_B_1']));
$var_C_1=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_C_1']));

$var_A_2=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_A_2']));
$var_B_2=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_B_2']));
$var_C_2=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_C_2']));
```

Entonces como los podría recibir con un for() ? masomenos como lo siguiente:

```
for($n=1; $n<$_POST['cantidad']; $n++){
$var_A_.$n=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_A_.$n']));
$var_B_.$n=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_B_.$n']));
$var_C_.$n=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_C_.$n']));
}
```

Resultado: Tener la variable con los nombres:

```
echo $var_A_1 
echo $var_B_1 

echo $var_A_2 
echo $var_B_2
 
echo $var_A_3 
echo $var_B_3
```

En total con las letras desde A hasta N Y los numeros desde 1 hasta 20 o 30, quedan como 300 o 400 variables.

Comment: Cómo te fue con ese intento que muestras ahí? Qué falló?

Comment: Con el ejemplo que puse para explicarlo, salen Undefined Variable y Undefined Index;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la página de las [variables variables](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.variable.php) del manual de PHP te dan algunas soluciones.
Prueba con esta:

```
for($n=1; $n<$_POST['cantidad']; $n++){
    ${'var_A_'.$n} = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_A_'.$n]));
    ${'var_B_'.$n} = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_B_'.$n]));
    ${'var_C_'.$n} = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_C_'.$n]));
}
```

Si son más letras y se te vuelven a crear igualmente demasiadas líneas de código prueba así:

```
$letras = ["A","B","C","D","E"]; // las que sean necesarias
for($n=1; $n<$_POST['cantidad']; $n++){
    foreach($letras as $letra) {
        ${'var_'.$letra'_'.$n} = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_'.$letra.'_'.$n]));
    }
}
```

Y quizás, para evitar fallos imprevistos de índice no encontrado en los POST, y gestionar un número variable y/o indeterminado de letras y números, deberías hacerlo así:

```
$letras = ["A","B","C","D","E"]; // las que sean necesarias
for($n=1; $n<$_POST['cantidad']; $n++){
    foreach($letras as $letra) {
        // verifica si el POST de la variable existe
        if (isset($_POST['var_'.$letra.'_'.$n])) {
            ${'var_'.$letra'_'.$n} = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['var_'.$letra.'_'.$n]));
        }
    }
}
```

de este modo, aunque tengas definidas más letras o números de los realmente recibidos por $_POST, solo se generarán los que existan.

Ejemplo simple basado en tu comentario:

```
$n = 10;
$letra = "B";
${$letra.$n} = "Esto funciona";
echo $B10;
```

devuelve:

```
Esto funciona
```

Ya dirás si te ha funcionado.

Comment: Sale Undefined variable y si la defino antes con "0", la salida igual queda con "0".

 Y si creo una variable así: ${'$variable'.$n}=0; igual sale undefined

Comment: En cual de los tres casos?  Por cierto, no encierres nunca una variable entre comillas simples pues no será interpretada, sino que será puro texto. Es decir, no pongas `${'$variable'.$n}` sino que pon `${$variable.$n}`

Comment: He ampliado mi respuesta con un ejemplo

Comment: Perdón; yo cometí un error y tu acabas de compiar mi mismo error: poner un $ de más.

Así como tu lo habías puesto desde el inicio sí funciona: es decir así: ${'variable'.$n}=0;  

Gracias. Ahora solo me falta el numero del POST

Comment: Léeme bien todo lo que he ido diciendo. No veo ningún fallo en ninguna parte  de mi respuesta. ¿donde dices que esta mal exactamente?

Comment: Desde tu primer respuesta pusiste así: ${'var_A_'.$n} y yo lo puse con un $ de más ${'$var_A_'.$n} por eso no me funcionó.

Pero ya me funciona todo así:
${'variable'.$n}=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['variable'.$n]));

Y curiosamente eN el ejemplo que pones de B10 : No me funciona:
${$variable.$n}=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['variable'.$n]));

Comment: No te funciona porque seria así:  `${$variable.$n}=htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST[$variable.$n]));`  (es decir, asegúrate que lo que pongas en la primera parte encerrada entre llaves `{}` es lo mismo que pones en el POST).   Pero este caso concreto era un ejemplo por si te daba por definir `$variable` y `$n` **antes** de esa línea, sino no te funcionará.